# ¿Como validar que un tipo de dato boolean no este nulo/vació en Java?

Tags: java, validación, booleano

Tengo la siguiente clase con algunos campos

```html
  public class EjemploEntradas{
    
    @Getter @Setter private String tipo;
    @Getter @Setter private String cliente;
    @Getter @Setter private String empresa;
    @Getter @Setterprivate String puesto;
    @Getter @Setter private boolean indProcesoA;

}
```

y el siguiente método que se encarga de validar que los campos no estén vacíos y si es así mandar un código de error, pero como puedo validar el campo booleano? siempre debe de venir un true o un false, no puede estar vació o nulo, como se hace eso?

```html
public sttaic void validarEntradas(EjemploEntradas request){

    boolean valido = true;
    if(Util.isBlank(request.getTipo())){
        valido = false;
    }else if(Util.isBlank(request.getCliente())){
        valido = false;
    }else if(Util.isBlank(request.getEmpresa())){
        valido = false;
    }else if(Util.isBlank(request.getPuesto())){
        valido = false;
    }
    
    if(!valido){
        throw new SecurityException(CodeError.ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ningún tipo primitivo puede ser null. Por qué hacer esa validación?

Comment: ¿Por qué metiste el código en snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo boolean no soporta nulos, si de verdad necesitas validar eso, podrías transformar el tipo de dato a Boolean